# How to parse and selectNodes in tDOM when the HTML/XML tags are preceded by namespaces?

Tags: html, xml, tcl, tdom

I'm trying to work with HTML files (in tDOM) in which every HTML tag is prefixed with an "a0:" such as `<a0:span class="...">`. The html tag is `<a0:html xmlns:a0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="//www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`.

So, I tried `[$doc selectNodes -namespaces {a0 http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml} $path]` which works if $path always includes the namespace such as `a0:html/a0:body//a0:div[@class="..."]` for example. Is there a way to get tDOM to focus on the html tags only regardless of the namespace?

I've tried the flag `-ignorexmlns` in the `[dom parse ...]` but that allows for locating only a path of `html/body`; once the div is included in the path it returns nothing. So, I must be doing something wrong.

I can keep including the "a0:" in all the paths; for it's no big issue, but would like to know if this can be done. Thank you.

---

```
set doc [dom parse -html5 -keepEmpties $inputDocument]
set nsFlag {a0 http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}
set path {a0:html/a0:body//a0:div[@class="main"]//a0:table[@class="type1"]}
foreach table [$doc selectNodes -namespaces $nsFlag $path] {
  # Generates output
}

set doc [dom parse -html5 -keepEmpties -ignorexmlns $inputDocument]
set path {html/body//div[@class="main"]//table[@class="type1"]}
foreach table [$doc selectNodes $path] {
  # Does not generate output
}
```

In the documentation for [-ignorexmlns](http://tdom.org/index.html/file?name=doc/dom.html&ci=release) it reads:

> -ignorexmlns
> It is recommended, that you only use this option with the -html5 option. If this option is given, no node within the created DOM tree
> will be internally marked as placed into an XML Namespace, even if
> there is a default namespace in scope for un-prefixed elements or even
> if the element has a defined namespace prefix. One consequence is that
> XPath node expressions on such a DOM tree doesn't work as may be
> expected. Prefixed element nodes can't be selected naively and element
> nodes without prefix will be seen by XPath expressions as if they are
> not in any namespace (no matter if they are in fact should be in a
> default namespace). If you need to inject prefixed node names into an
> XPath expression use the '%' syntax described in the documentation of
> the of the domNode command method >selectNodes.

In the documentation for [selectNodes](http://tdom.org/index.html/file?name=doc/domNode.html&ci=release) I haven't found reference to the '%'.

I tried using the '%' in place of 'a0' in $path and $nsFlag and leaving the `-namespace` flag in, but without success.

Comment: It's better to use than ignore namespaces, so if you have it working with the `a0` prefixes, then it'd be a step backward to get it working without the namespace prefixes.

Comment: If you insist on ignoring them, you can do so at the XPath level by testing the name in a predicate:  `*[local-name()='div']`, but that's even less visually appealing than `a0:div`.  If you want to ignore them at the `tdom` level, then post a [mcve] showing how `-ignorexmlns` wasn't working for you as that flag should have helped in your (ill-advised) bid to ignore namespaces.

Comment: `-ignorexmlns` works for me just fine. pls provide an MRE and indicate the tDOM version used.

Comment: @mrcalvin @kjhughes Thanks. I added some sample code but, of course, it's not reproducible because there's not an html file upon which to run it. There's only on namespace and it seems to have been added in by the JS `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)` that was ued to store the file.

Comment: @Gary your MRE works for me with `set inputDocument {<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Title of document</title></head><body><div class="main"><table class="type1"><tr><td></td></tr></table></div></body></html>}` as input, with and without `-html5`. Why not post a minimal excerpt from your XHTML document? This is with tDOM 0.9.3.

Comment: Question: Why turning HTML into XHTML if no need be? Rather use `document.documentElement.outerHTML` to serialize the HTML content.

Comment: @mrcalvin Thank you. I forgot to post the tDom version; 0.9.2-1. After posting my last comment, I found that even the `foreach` block that I thought was working properly was not; for each `$table` contained all the table nodes. So, I was stumped and thought my code was wrong; and after awhile I read over XMLSerializer again and decided to toss it for `outerHTML` and then everything worked fine. Don't need a namespace or`- html5`.

Comment: I ran that same serializer code on two seperate sets of web pages and one wrote as HTML and the other XHTML with namespace a0. I can't say it was the serializer or something in those pages or something I was still doing incorrectly with tDOM; but the Tcl tDom code is just about identical between the two attempts. I should've known better to not use the serializer for this purpose; never tried it before.

Comment: Fine that this seems resolved from your end, but it would be more satisfying to see an exemplary XHTML document that can be used to reproduce your observation. Why not post it, or a minimal derivative?

Comment: @mrcalvin I'll try to do so. It's just that they are very large files due to having messages that appear on hover stored in the title attributes; and there's a lot of data on each page. I'll try to reduce it to something smaller. I suspect that they are very old pages; at least the DOM structure, but still work and provide a good service. There are `<br>` tags in the page and I noticed the serializer add closing br tags but not next to the start tag.

Comment: XPath and XML Namespaces go together like chalk and cheese. It's a major standards fluff by the W3C.